# Cor function in R using car dataset

Tags: r

Using this correlation as the test statistic, how do i implement a permutation test of the null hypothesis that mpg and wt are uncorrelated?

```
with(mtcars, cor(mpg, wt))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do use `sample()`, you permute the order of mpg:

```
with(mtcars,sample(mpg))
 [1] 15.2 22.8 21.4 19.7 15.8 10.4 15.5 21.0 30.4 27.3 17.8 18.7 14.7 13.3 21.5
[16] 30.4 17.3 22.8 21.4 21.0 32.4 33.9 15.0 15.2 24.4 19.2 10.4 18.1 26.0 19.2
[31] 14.3 16.4
```

This should have no correlation to wt (since it is permuted) , so we repeat the correlation with this sampled mpg 1000x :

```
perm_cor = replicate(1000,with(mtcars, cor(sample(mpg), wt)))
```

We plot and see where your true correlation is:

```
obs = with(mtcars, cor(mpg, wt))
hist(perm_cor,br=20,xlim=c(-1,1))
abline(v=obs,lty=8,col="blue")
```

So the probability of getting an abs(correlation) higher than what you see, using what is defined in this [publication](https://doi.org/10.2202/1544-6115.1585), so that you don't have p-value =0 :

```
(sum(abs(perm_cor)>=abs(obs))+1)/(length(perm_cor)+1)
[1] 0.000999001
```